# Is it possible to configure throttling for WebSocket APIS in API Gateway using the Serveless Framework?

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, serverless

I would like to control the rate at which clients can connect to my WebSocket API running in AWS API Gateway. The `provider.usagePlan` config allows me to do this for `private` HTTP endpoints, via an API key set in `provider.apiKeys`. Is there an equivalent for WebSockets?